# A counterexample for a Theorem of Hirsch on the Cohomology of a nilpotent group over a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

The mathematician Morris W.Hirsch wrote on 1977 the paper "Flat Manifolds and the Cohomology of Groups". The Theorem C establishes the following:

Theorem C: Let $G$ a nilpotent group acting linearly on a finite dimensional vector space $M$ over the field $F$. If $H^{0}(G,M)=0$, then $H^{k}(G,M)=0$, for all $k\geq 0$

I want to know if there is a counterexample when $G$ is a solvable notnilpotent group. Remember that $G$ acts linearly on $M$ it means  that there is an operation $"\cdot": G\times M\rightarrow M$ such that:

(1) $g\cdot (x_{1}+x_{2})=g\cdot x_{1}+g\cdot x_{2}$, for all $g\in G; x_{1},x_{2}\in M$.

(2) $(g_{1}g_{2})\cdot x= g_{1}\cdot (g_{2}\cdot x)$, for all $g_{1},g_{2}\in G; x\in M$.

(3) $1_{G}\cdot x=x$, for all $x\in M$

(4) $g\cdot (\lambda x)=\lambda (g\cdot x)$, for all $g\in G, \lambda\in F,x\in M$

My Aproach: I have showed with an elementary proof that this Theorem C is valid for any group $G$ and $M=F$. So, I think that maybe a counterexample can be found for the case $M= F^{2}$ or $M= F^{3}$.

Comment: Consider the s.e.s. $0 \to F \to F^2 \to F \to 0$, from which we get the l.e.s.
$$
0 \to H^0(G,F) \to H^0 (G,F^2) \to H^0 (G,F) \to H^1(G,F) \to
$$
$$
\to H^1(G,F^2) \to H^1(G,F) \to H^2(G,F) \to \cdots
$$

If $G$ is a group such that $H^0(G,F)=0$, then by your elementary proof that this automatically implies $H^k(G,F)=0$ for $k > 0$, we conclude that $H^k(G,F^2)=0$ for all $k \ge 0$. Since every s.e.s. of finite dimensional vector spaces splits, you should be able to do the same thing for any $F^n$ by induction. So I would think that something is not quite right here.

Comment: @Tabes Bridges: we’re speaking of exact sequences of $F$-vector spaces *with a $G$-module structure*, that is, representations of $G$ over $F$! And there can be irreducible representations of degree more than $1$, which aren’t accessible with this method.

Comment: Oof, fair point! I almost left something to the effect of "Disclaimer: I have worked with most common cohomology theories *other* than group cohomology, so take all of this with a grain of salt" at the end, but I ran out of characters.